# Regex assistance - do not match specific string

Tags: regex

I have the following REGEX:

`/(?:(?:src|href|poster|altimg|data)\s*=\s*)(?!['"]?(?:http|#|mailto:|data:|tel:|sms:))['"]([^'">]+)|(?:url\()(?!['"]?(?:http))['"]?([^'")]+)/gm`

In case in the string contains a substring which is `data-href`, it matches it.

For example:

`<figure class="figure--fullwidth figure--linked" data-figure-id="w-3-1" data-index="20"><a class="figure__link" data-href="..\images\W-3-1.png" tabindex="0" data-size="1218x920" data-index="21"><img class="figure__image figure__thumbnail" alt="" src="../images/W-3-1.png" data-image-id="w-3-1" data-index="22" data-size="%7B%22width%22%3A1218%2C%22height%22%3A920%7D"></a></figure>`

Here it matches `data-href="..\images\W-3-1.png"` I don't want to match it, only in case the string is `href.....`.

How can modify the regex that it will only match cases when it's `href` and not `data-href`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start your regex with a negative lookbehind `(?<!\S)`

Comment: @anubhava tried this: (?:(?<!\data-href)(?:src|^-href|href|^data-href|poster|altimg|data)\s*=\s*)(?!['"]?(?:http|#|mailto:|data:|tel:|sms:))['"]([^'">]+)|(?:url\()(?!['"]?(?:http))['"]?([^'")]+), but it still matches the `href` part of `data-href`.

Comment: if it's the only case think it's will be more easy if you just filtered your match array `arr.filter(item => String(item).indexOf('href="..\\images\\W-3-1.png"') == -1)`

Comment: @JS_INF, I need it for all cases where the string contains `data-href`

Comment: You mean that you don't want to match href at all ?

Comment: @JS_INF I don't want it to match `data-href` but I do want it to match when its only `href`

Comment: @DavidFaizulaev: That is not what I suggested. Try: `/(?<!\S)(?:(?:src|href|poster|altimg|data)\s*=\s*)(?!['"]?(?:http|#|mailto:|data:|tel:|sms:))['"]([^'">]+)|(?:url\()(?!['"]?(?:http))['"]?([^'")]+)/`

Comment: Why don't you change `href` into `(?<!data-)href` inside the non-capture group's alternatives? Or maybe even better, the above suggestion from anubhava.

Comment: @JvdV I tried anubhava suggestion, but as in the comment I wrote, I placed it in the start of the regex and it did not work. Maybe I need to place it somewhere else?

Comment: [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ke6BIi/1)

Comment: @anubhava it looks good, but the match does not display character index numbers for `../images/W-3-1.png` match. is that okay? or that might cause an issue?

Comment: @anubhava nvm, its irelevant. Please post your solution as an answer so I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negative lookbehind assertion to make sure to match only specified attributes using your regex:

```js
/(?<!\S)(?:(?:src|href|poster|altimg|data)\s*=\s*)(?!['"]?(?:http|#|mailto:|data:|tel:|sms:))['"]([^'">]+)|(?:url\()(?!['"]?(?:http))['"]?([^'")]+)/
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ke6BIi/1)

`(?<!\S)` is negative lookbehind assertion that doesn't allow any non-whitespace character before matching your attributes.